# pure html5 vs jquery mobile/angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, jquery-mobile, cordova

We are developing a cross platform mobile application using pure HTML5/JavaScript/CSS. We are using Bootstrap for the responsive UI. And using Cordova we will be packaging the app to Android and iOS. I heard that I can reduce the development effort and can code more structured if I am using the JQueryMobile or AngularJS along with HTML5/JavaScript/CSS.

Can you somebody tell me about how these frameworks can help me in the development?

Answer (score 6):

You will get tons of results and answers why you should and why you shouldn't. Someone will recommend one framework, and someone will go against it. Search Google you'll see them.

AFAIK the biggest reason to using framework like JQM / Angularjs is to give the application a native look and feel. Only html5 design will create a website, frameworks make them mobile applications.

Ajax page navigation model, responsiveness, similar design for all browsers, MVC, less code writing, DOM Manipulation these are the reasons why anyone need frameworks. On the other hand there are quirks too.

See these links to get a clear view.

[Choosing the right HTML5 technologies for your Web and Mobile Application.](http://britesnow.com/blog/choosing-the-right-html5-technology)

[10 Reasons Why You Should Use AngularJS](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-reasons-use-angularjs/)

[Five reasons to use jQuery mobile](http://www.creativebloq.com/jquery/five-reasons-use-jquery-mobile-4135691)